# Plotting points on the horizontal line

Tags: plotting

I have list such as

```
list = {1, 5, 2, 6, 3,...}
```

and I need to plot the numbers from the list on a horizontal line such that there will be on a place on horizontal line which will correspond to the number itself plus all the previous numbers.

Using the above-mentioned list:

1 will be plotted at the place of number 1;
5 will be plotted at the place of number 6;
2 will be plotted at the place of number 8;
6 will be plotted at the place of number 14 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {1, 5, 2, 6, 3};
NumberLinePlot[list]
```

[image]

```
NumberLinePlot[Accumulate@list]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{list,Accumulate@list}]]
```

[image]

**Update:**

> ... on the horizontal axis, there would be instead of accumulated numbers, dates that correspond to to the accumulated number
>
> ... in case of one graph ... there are selected months on the horizontal.

```
list2 = RandomInteger[100, 50]; DateListPlot[
 Transpose[{DayPlus[{1999, 1, 2}, #] & /@ Accumulate@list2, list2}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{{2000, 1}, {2001, 4}, {2002, 2}, {2002, 11}, 
    {2003, 7}, {2003, 12}, {2004, 8}}, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthName", "\n", "Year"}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, @kguler. You also made me realize that plot it in 2D will be better. Can I also ask you whether it can be done that on the horizontal axis, there would be instead of accumulated numbers, dates that correspond to to the accumulated number -> I have also a list of DateObjects  -> e.g. if the accumulated number equals to 6, the date that is within 6 days from the first day in a list will appear on a horizontal line (or better, only just few of such a dates will appear otherwise it would not be possible to read it

Comment: @rabbit, maybe something like: `DateListPlot[List/@Transpose[{DayPlus[Today,#]&/@Accumulate@list,list}],PlotMarkers->(Style[#,20]&/@list),ImageSize->500]`?

Comment: which list in your code is the list with DateObjects (since I have the dates in separate list)? ...or maybe it would also suffice to add the dates manuály such as {{1999, 1, 2},{2000, 1, 2}}.

Comment: @rabbit3698741, `DayPlus[Today,#]&/@Accumulate@list`.

Comment: OK so i tried

`DateListPlot[
 List /@ Transpose[{DayPlus[{1999, 1, 2}, #] & /@ 
     Accumulate@list, list}], 
 PlotMar‌​kers -> (Style[#, 20]&/@list), ImageSize -> 500]`, where list is the same list as mentioned in your main answer and it returns me: Unknown option PlotMar‌​kers... @kguler

Comment: @rabbit3698741, there seems to be some corruption of the text `PlotMarkers` during copy/paste;  that's why it is highlighted red, and gives the Unknown option message. Just erase the red-highlighted text and retype `PlotMarkers` to fix it.

Comment: you are right, that was due to some error when copying the code. However, now on the graph there are also plotted the numbers similarly as in solution proposed by shrx. If I want just dots to be plotted? @kguler

Comment: @rabbit3698741, just remove the part `PlotMarkers->...`

Comment: It works, thanks. @kguler. The last question: I have several graphs and in case of one graph, instead of years, there are selected months on the horizontal. Is it possible to adjust that manually and not let the Mathematica to do this automatically? Do you know how to do it? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @rabbit3698741, you can specify the ticks on the horizontal axis using `FrameTicks` and their format using `DateTicksFormat`; please see the updated post.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {1, 5, 2, 6, 3};
ListPlot[{#} & /@ 
  Transpose[{Accumulate[list], Table[1, {Length[list]}]}], 
 PlotMarkers -> list, Axes -> {True, False}, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks! It also works. However, I realized that the solution given by kguler will be more appropriate for my needs @shrx.

Comment: @rabbit3698741 no problem, although I think my solution is more relevant to what you are asking. You should consider this when you decide to accept an answer (you can accept only one).